# Compiling a class method in squeak in run-time

Tags: runtime, squeak, class-method

I would like to add a class method during run time in squeak.
I know that there is a method compile, which is defined in Behaviour class, but this one adds the new method I want to the class Instance methods. Is there a way to compile it to the class methods (so it will be a method which is defined for the class, and not for an instance of the class).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As every class is itself an object, a class itself has a class, too. This class is an instance of `Metaclass`, which inherits from `Behavior`. Thus, you can use `#compile:` on a class's class for class methods just like you would on a class for instance methods.

A simple example:

An instance method on `Number`:

```
Number compile: 
'succ
   ^ self + 1
'
```

A class method on `Number class`:

```
Number class compile:
'one
    ^ self zero + 1
'
```